# Page break only between tbody when printing from Chrome

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table, page-break

I have a `<table>` of data where consecutive rows are conceptually related and need to stay together. I've group each pair of rows in a `<tbody>` tag. When it comes time to print the table, I want to make sure that page breaks only happen between `<tbody>` tags.

I've tried some variations of `page-break-inside: avoid` and `page-break-after: auto`, but can't seem to get it to work in Chrome 42 (see screenshot below)

[image: Conceptual group of rows split across two pages... what I don't want]

However, it does seems to work as expected in Firefox 40 and IE 11 though. It looks like `page-break-*` might only apply to block level elements. Is there a good way to accomplish this in html/css?

Example code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 70%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        thead {
            display: table-header-group;
            text-align: left;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
        }
        tbody {
            page-break-inside: avoid;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project #</th>
                <th>Owner</th>
                <th>% Complete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>HR-123</td>
                <td>Arther Dent</td>
                <td>42%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='3'>Description: Find travel guide to get me back to earth.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>RD-123</td>
                <td>Frodo Baggins</td>
                <td>9%</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='3'>Description: Find a better way to get the ring to Mordor.</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <!-- repeat tbody sections as necessary to get onto the second page -->
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkdkejfs/) that'll give you a bit of an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

*Edit:* I considering not using a table but didn't since (i) I want my columns to line up, and (ii) I really don't want to hard-code column widths to make sure they're all the same.

Comment: I'm not much experienced with tables yet, but I'd recommend you to use some divs with display:inline-block and span because the tables are a bit complex...

Comment: Tip: Avoid page-break properties inside tables, floating elements, and block elements with borders.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it all in a 
make that specific  a block element (http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html)
then use page-break-*

Comment: Which element are you suggesting to make `inline-block`? Or are you suggesting abandoning the table layout entirely? I tried it on `<tbody>` but that resulted in my columns not lining up (which is a requirement in my case).

Comment: Additional elements between `<table>` and `<td>` are not valid. You can try to add block elements inside the `<td>`, and apply the `page-break-inside: avoid` to those.